# MethodInfo.Invoke throws unexpected exception

Tags: c#, exception, invoke, methodinfo

Im trying to make a custom shell.

```
public static void CallMethod(string method, string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            Type type = typeof(Program);
            MethodInfo methodInfo = type.GetMethod(method);
            methodInfo.Invoke(method, args);
        }
        catch(TargetException)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The method + '" + method + "' does not exist.");
        }
        catch(TargetParameterCountException)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The parameter count for '" + method +"' does not fit.");
        }
        catch(Exception)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("An unexpected error occured.");
        }
    }
```

I am expecting `TargetException` to be thrown when the `method`-string doesnt contain an existing method - like the MS documentation says. But in this case the `Exception` is thrown. Little example: There is no function `example()`, so it should throw `TargetException` when `method` contains `"example"`, but it seems that another Exception is thrown

My question ist what exception is thrown in this specific case?

Comment: Where does it say that? I would expect `methodInfo` to equal `null` if the method does not exist and `Invoke` to cause a null-deref exception in that case.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError Copied from Microsoft: "TargetException The obj parameter is null and the method is not static. -or- The method is not declared or inherited from obj's class. -or- A static constructor is called and obj is neither null nor an instance of the class that declared the constructor."

Comment: I don't know where you're copying from, but [my docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.type.getmethod#system-type-getmethod(system-string)) list only `ArgumentNullException` and `AmbiguousMatchException` as possible outcomes of `Type.GetMethod(string)`. We never get to `Invoke` if there is no method. (As an aside, this is why you don't put up a generic handler for `Exception`, or if you do, at the very least never fail to inspect the `.Message`.)

Comment: Also note that `methodInfo.Invoke(method, args)` is clearly incorrect -- you're trying to invoke a method on an object, that object is not the method name itself. If there is no target object because the method is static, `null` has to be used.

Comment: @JeroenMostert `GetMethod(string)` returns null if there is no method declared with this name, it does not throw an exception. It only throws an exception if its parameter is null. But the `Invoke()` should throw the exception if it tries to call Method with `MethodInfo == null` and this is - according to the ms docs - the `TargetException`.

Comment: No -- invoking any instance method on a `null`-valued expression always produces a `NullReferenceException` (the only time this doesn't necessarily happen is if an extension method is involved, but that's not the case here). This happens before the method is ever called, so it doesn't get to have a say about the kind of exception thrown. The docs only ever apply to invoking methods on non-`null` instances.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Ah, I got it. Thanks, now it's working as expected.